# Python - Import modules overhead

Tags: python, import, module

I have a project with a few modules. I am troubled by the overhead of importing them since it takes 7 seconds. The imports are like this:

```py
import fempy.smartplot as splt

from fempy.fem.preprocessor import rectangular_mesh_model
from fempy.fem.problems import ProblemStructuralDynamic
from fempy.fem.analyzers import Linear, NewmarkDynamicAnalyzer
from fempy.fem.solvers import CholeskySolver
from fempy.fem.systems import LinearSystem

from fempy.fem.core.loads import TimeDependentLoad
from fempy.fem.core.entities import DOFtype
from fempy.fem.core.providers import ElementMaterialOnlyStiffnessProvider, RayleighDampingMatrixProvider
from fempy.fem.core.materials import ElasticMaterial2D, StressState2D
from fempy.fem.core.elements import Quad4
from fempy.fem.problems import ProblemStructuralDynamic
```

I have added my project to `pythonpath`, profiled the code in Spyder and gives the following:

[image: Profiler results]

**Is it expected to take that long? Or do I miss something here?**

This is my `sys.path` output:

```
['C:\\Users\\constatza\\Documents\\thesis\\fempy\\tests', # script run in this dir
 'C:\\Users\\constatza\\Documents\\Διπλωματική\\PlainStress\\fempy', # doesn't even exist
 '',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\constatza\\Documents\\thesis',    # <- THIS IS THE DIRECTORY FROM WHICH THE PACKAGES ARE IMPORTED 
 'C:\\Users\\constatza\\Documents\\thesis\\fempy\\tests',
 'C:\\Users\\constatza\\Miniconda3\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\constatza\\Miniconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\constatza\\Miniconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\constatza\\Miniconda3',
 'C:\\Users\\constatza\\Miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\constatza\\Miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\constatza\\Miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\constatza\\Miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\constatza\\Miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\constatza\\.ipython']
```

The weird is that the 2nd path from the list, *does not even exist* and I don't know how it got in there either.

Comment: I wouldn't _necessarily_ be too worried about this. Remember that any code at the module level is run "during import", and that may well include your main function that's actually doing the work. I suspect if you kept digging into `builtins.exec` and `builtins.__import__` you'd find some real computations that you want. It's possible I'm wrong about this, but it's worth keeping expanding the profiling list until you're sure

Comment: I will check it, thanks.